# Mac user wants to try Linux

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

I'm a Mac user and I **want to try different Linux distros** (just anything that is not made by huge corporations).

I'm coming from **Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3** and am now on **Fedora 36**. Because the UI structure seems more familiar with macOS (yes, Apple fan but not that kind of them) Is there anything else you would recommend me?

Trying just for the sake of it and to maybe get into some coding. It is **not likely that I will daily drive it** but rather would use it occasionally for some experimenting.

The specs for my *experimenting-laptop* are:

**Sony Vaio SVE1712C1EW**
Intel Pentium B980
Intel Graphics 2000
4GiB of RAM

Recommendations would be very nice (something that doesn't blow my Laptop) :))

Comment: Hm, kind of asking for opinions there, which usually doesn't fly well with the rules of this site, but nevertheless: basically all Linux distros would work for you, so take one that has a good user base and nice installer. That's Ubuntu, mint, fedora, Alma, Manjaro, opensuse these days. Pick a slim and low-memory desktop environment, which would suggest the xfce variants of Ubuntu (i.e., https://xubuntu.org) or fedora (the [xfce spin](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/xfce/)). Any software available for basically any distro will trivially be installable on each of these.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you settle on Fedora then? Linux distros contain almost the same software with slight differences here and there. The desktop UI that you get/see is called "Desktop Environment" and you can trivially install and use something different.

The most prominent desktop environments are:

- Gnome (that's what Fedora defaults to)
- KDE
- XFCE
- Cinnamon
- Mate
- TDE (Trinity Desktop Environment)
- Enlightenment

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/desktop_environment